# Finding the 4 consecutive numbers of the same value - vertically and diagonally

Tags: java, matrix

I have to find how many vertical and diagonal lines have 4 consecutive number of the same value in the matrix (8x7). If I'm right, there are 2 vertical lines and 4 diagonal lines.

2 *1* 1 6 1 0 0

2 1 *1* *7* 6 0 *1*

1 1 *7* *1* 6 *1* 1

*9* *7* 6 0 *1* 1 6

*7* *9* 1 *1* 6 9 *0*

*7* 5 *9* 2 2 2 *0*

*7* 5 9 *9* 9 9 *0*

*7* 1 1 1 1 0 *0*

But when I run it:

*# of Vertical Lines: 3*

Would anybody know how to fix this problem? I asked a similar question earlier but with the horizontal lines and I applied what was given there but it won't work.

Also I am very confused as to how to find the diagonal lines, would anybody know how to do this?

```
public class Q5_Numbers{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[][] matrix = {
            {2, 1, 1, 6, 1, 0, 0},
            {2, 1, 1, 7, 6, 0, 1},
            {1, 1, 7, 1, 6, 1, 1},
            {9, 7, 6, 0, 1, 1, 6},
            {7, 9, 1, 1, 6, 9, 0},
            {7, 5, 9, 2, 2, 2, 0},
            {7, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0},
            {7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}
        }; 

        // # of vertical Lines = 2 
        System.out.printf("# of vertical lines: %d\n", findVertical(matrix));

        // # of diagonal lines = 4;
        System.out.printf("# of diagonal lines: %d\n", findDiagonal(matrix));

    }

    public static int findVertical(int[][] values){
        int countV = 0;
        int found = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++){ 
            int current = values[0][j];
            for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
                if(values[i][j] == current){
                    found++;
                    if(found == 4){
                        countV++;
                        found = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return countV;
    }

    public static int findDiagonal(int[][] values){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing for you to understand: the central element of such exercises is to figure the *algorithm* yourself. Thus, start with that example matrix, and a piece of paper and a pen. And then observe yourself, how you as a human would solve this problem. For example, you could go: *I start with the very first cell. I have to compare it with the 3 cells "right" to it (or below it). Then I move to the next cell, and so on.* Then you have to ask yourself: how do I denote that idea "3 cells below" in java terms. And then you simply start adding values to your first/second index, to ...

Comment: ... get to specific elements in the matrix. Cells to the right: rowIndex, colIndex+1 and rowIndex, colIndex+2, .. Cells below: rowIndex+1, colIndex and rowIndex+2, colIndex ... and diagonal: rowIndex+1, colIndex+1... for example.

Comment: The tricky part are cornercases, like: not trying to find cells that would have indexes outside of your matrix.

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you for the advice but I did do that but in my head it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @GhostCat: is correct.  You don't get to just code in learning or in life.  You have to learn how to decompose problems and simplify the problem, then you get to code.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc And like I said I have tried to work it ou and drawing it out on paper. But in my head it still doesn't make sense even if it seems simple to you guys :)

Comment: Look at your loop code. Take a piece of paper, and "run" it manually. Check the values of i and j. Your code is looping over BOTH X and Y, so all rows, all columns. But I told you: vertical elements have the SAME column, just different rows. And note: nobody said this is *simple*. It is complicated, but it is your homework, and it wouldnt help you if other people solve it for you. I sometimes spent a whole weekend on such things many years back. Write code, experiment. Such things.

Comment: @GhostCat I did do that but I'm not sure how to fix this. I take back what I said about simple but I've been working on this program for 3-4 days now and I usually come here as the last resort before giving up and handing it in the way it is.

Comment: And I told you were to look at. Right now, you  have a simple for loop that just walks all cells, comparing them to the very first value. Sorry, but I really do not intend to do your homework for you. I told you what you need to look at: writing (different) loops that compare m(i, j) with m(i+1, j) with m(i, j+2) with m(i, j+3) for example. Ask yourself: how do I express "the next 4 cells in the same row" (or column). And if this assignment really overburdens you like this, you should rather sit down with your peer students, your tutor, your instructor.

Comment: @GhostCat I'd love to but quarantining and doing online classes in my dorm in a foreign country doesn't help. I'm not asking you to do my homework, I'm just asking for a clear explanation because its already confusing to me

Answer (score 0):

### Introduction

For the benefit of future readers of this question, I'm going to show how to work out the solution.

From the question:

> I have to find how many vertical and diagonal lines have 4 consecutive
>   numbers of the same value in the matrix (8x7).

To state this in a more formal way.

1. Find the number of vertical lines that have four consecutive numbers of the same value.
2. Find the number of diagonal lines that have four consecutive numbers of the same value.

First, we have a two-dimensional array.  Each row has 7 values.  Each column has 8 values.  That means the row indexes go from 0 to 6, and the column indexes go from 0 to 7.  Java has zero-based indexes.

```
    int[][] matrix = {
        {2, 1, 1, 6, 1, 0, 0},
        {2, 1, 1, 7, 6, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 7, 1, 6, 1, 1},
        {9, 7, 6, 0, 1, 1, 6},
        {7, 9, 1, 1, 6, 9, 0},
        {7, 5, 9, 2, 2, 2, 0},
        {7, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0},
        {7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}
    };
```

### Vertical LInes

So, how do we check if the first 4 numbers in the first column?  Remember, this is pencil and paper thinking.

The first four numbers are at indexes [0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], and [3, 0].  Do we see a pattern here?

Well, the second index, the row index, remains at zero.  The first index, the column index, increments by one for each column were going down in the matrix.

So how would you do this in code?

Our first try might look something like this.

```
int temp = matrix[0, 0];
if (matrix[1, 0] == temp && matrix[2, 0] == temp
        && matrix[3, 0] == temp) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Remember. we're not trying to write efficient code.  We're trying to write code that helps us to understand the problem and works.

So, let's walk through what happens in the code we just wrote.

```
int temp = matrix[0, 0];
int temp = 2;
```

So is `matrix[1, 0] = 2`?

Yes, it is.

How about `matrix[2, 0]`?  Is it equal to 2?

Nope, `matrix[2, 0]` is equal to 1.  Oh well, the `else` condition happens, and the code we wrote returns `false`.

Now, we could copy this bit of code we wrote, changing the column and row subscripts with each copy.  But there's a better way.  Let's generalize the code.

Here's what we started with.

```
int temp = matrix[0, 0];
if (matrix[1, 0] == temp && matrix[2, 0] == temp
        && matrix[3, 0]) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

So, how do we generalize this?

We start by making column a variable.

```
int column = 0;
int temp = matrix[column, 0];
if (matrix[column + 1, 0] == temp && matrix[column + 2, 0] == temp
        && matrix[column + 3, 0]) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

We take small steps to generalize our code.  Now, in our study, what allows us to increment a variable in a loop?

Why a `for` loop!

So, we can write the code like this.

```
int column = 0;
int temp = matrix[column, 0];
for (int i = column + 1; i < column + 4; i++) {
    if (temp != matrix[i, 0]) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

So, let's break down the `for` loop.  Remember, our code looked like this.

```
int column = 0;
int temp = matrix[column, 0];
if (matrix[column + 1, 0] == temp && matrix[column + 2, 0] == temp
        && matrix[column + 3, 0} == temp) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

So, you can see we took the `column + 1` right from the `if` statement.

The `column + 4` is a bit trickier.  In the `if` statement, we only went up to `column + 3`.  So why `column + 4`?

It's true.  We could have written the `for` loop like this.

```
for (int i = column + 1; i <= column + 3; i++) {
```

And that's ok.  In Java, the convention is to use the less than sign, rather than the less than or equal to sign to end a `for` loop.

But there's another reason we wrote the `for` loop this way.

```
for (int i = column + 1; i < column + 4; i++) {
```

The 4 represents the number of rows we want to check.  In other words, we're looking for 4 consecutive numbers that are equal.

Now, this part of the code.

```
    if (temp != matrix[i, 0]) {
        return false;
    }
```

Needs a little explanation.

We're looking for 4 consecutive numbers with the same value.  That means any value that's not the same makes the proposition false.  So, the first time a subsequent matrix value is not equal to the first matrix value, we can return `false`.

By the way, this is exactly how this if statement works "under the covers".

```
if (matrix[column + 1, 0] == temp && matrix[column + 2, 0] == temp
        && matrix[column + 3, 0} == temp) {
```

So, how can we generalize this code further?

Why, we can put it in a method!

```
private boolean checkVerticalLine(int column, int row,
        int depth) {
    int temp = matrix[column, row];
    for (int i = column + 1; i < column + depth; i++) {
        if (temp != matrix[i, row]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The major changes I made here were to pass the column and row in as parameters and pass the number of values we want to check (the `depth`).  This removes the "magic number" 4 from our code.

I'm getting tired and I'm not writing a book, so here's the code to count all the vertical lines that have four consecutive numbers;

```
int depth = 4;
int count = 0;
for (int column = 0; column <= (8 - depth); column++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
        if (checkVerticalLine(column, row, depth)) {
            count++;
        }
     }
 }
```

We don't have to go through all the starting columns.  If we did, we would get an index out of range error.  We only have to check starting columns 0 through 4.

In this case, I used the less than or equal sign in the column `for` statement, because it makes the math easier.

### Diagonal Lines

You use the same reasoning to solve for diagonal lines.

Let's again take the value at matrix[0, 0] as a starting point and write some pencil and paper code.

```
int temp = matrix[0, 0];
if (matrix[1, 1] == temp && matrix[2, 2] == temp
        && matrix[3, 3] == temp) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

The only difference here is that we're incrementing the column and the row by 1.  Skipping a lot of steps, we get to the following method.

```
private boolean checkDiagonalLine1(int column, int row,
        int depth) {
    int temp = matrix[column, row++];
    for (int i = column + 1; i < column + depth; i++) {
        if (temp != matrix[i, row++]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The only differences from the vertical lines method are the name of the method and that we increment the `row` value as well as the `column` value.  Since Java is pass-by-reference, we're not changing the value of `row` in the calling method.

The calling code would look like this.

```
int depth = 4;
int count = 0;
for (int column = 0; column <= (8 - depth); column++) {
    for (int row = 0; row <= (7 - depth); row++) {
        if (checkDiagonalLine1(column, row, depth)) {
            count++;
        }
     }
 }
```

We have to adjust both the starting column and the starting row values so we don't get an index out of range error.

We still have to check for the opposite diagonal lines.  Again, writing some pencil and paper code.

```
int temp = matrix[0, 0];
if (matrix[1, -1] == temp && matrix[2, -2] == temp
        && matrix[3, -3] == temp) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Wait!  We can't have negative subscripts!

Let's try again.  This time, we'll end with row zero.

```
int temp = matrix[0, 3];
if (matrix[1, 2] == temp && matrix[2, 1] == temp
        && matrix[3, 0] == temp) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Again generalizing and skipping a lot of steps, we end up with the following method.

```
private boolean checkDiagonalLine2(int column, int row,
        int depth) {
    int temp = matrix[column, row--];
    for (int i = column + 1; i < column + depth; i++) {
        if (temp != matrix[i, row--]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And the calling code would look like this.

```
int depth = 4;
int count = 0;
for (int column = (depth - 1); column < 8; column++) {
    for (int row = 0; row <= (7 - depth); row++) {
        if (checkDiagonalLine2(column, row, depth)) {
            count++;
        }
     }
 }
```

In this check, the starting columns go from 3 through 7.  The starting rows go from 0 through 4.

I hope this explanation helps someone.  Remember, we don't just get to code.  We have to figure out how to solve the problem.  Then we get to code.